# Insert xml file on hdfs to Hive Parquet Table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, cloudera, hue

tI have a gzipped 3GBs xml file that I want to map to Hive parquet table. 
I'm using xml serde for parsing that file to temporary external table and than I'm using INSERT to insert this data to hive parquet table (I want this data to by placed on Hive table, not create interface to xml file on HDFS).

I came up with this script:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY EXTERNAL TABLE temp_table (someData1 INT, someData2 STRING, someData3  ARRAY<STRING>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.someData1" ="someXpath1/text()",
"column.xpath.someData2"="someXpath2/text()",
"column.xpath.someData3"="someXpath3/text()",   
)

STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 'hdfs://locationToGzippedXmlFile'
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<MyItem>",
"xmlinput.end"="</MyItem>"
 );

CREATE TABLE parquet_table 
STORED AS Parquet 
AS select * from temp_table
```

Main point of this is that I want to have optimized way to access the data. I don't want to parse xml every query instead parse whole file once and put the result into parquet table. And running the script above is taking unlimited amount of time additionally in  log's i can see that only 1 mapper is used.

I don't really know if it's the correct approach (maybe it's possible to do that with partitions?)

BTW I'm using Hue with cloudera.

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question. Yes, your approach is quite common. In a lot of places they'd have a /raw dir with data as is (as it arrives from external sources). Your xmls would go there. Then there'd be something like /master dir which would contain the same data after cleaning it up and formatting it. Your parquet data would go there. The "xml" table doesn't have to be temporary.

Comment: If this is quite common are there any ways to optimize above query so it won't run forever?